# Is it possible to disable a windows keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, hotkeys, input-languages

Is it possible to disable any default windows keyboard shortcut? I want to reuse <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> for something else, but it is already taken by the system to switch between keyboard layouts. Windows 8 allows you to select a different shortcut for it, which I did restoring windows 7's shortcut.

I guess it is possible with AutoHotKey, but I don't want more stuff running, even if lightweight.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use <kbd>Windows</kbd>, <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keys to create a keyboard shortcut, at least not in shortcut properties window.